# Editing listView item in ObservableCollection calls XamlParseException (needs DependencyObject) - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, edit

I'm beginner in programming in C# and  WPF and I'm creating a file manager with 2 `ListView`s, all items bounded. In `ListView` there are some `GridViewColumn`s and first has `CellTemplate` because I want there icon of file/folder and its name. The `CellTemplate` is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IconTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=itemIcon}" Width="20" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=itemName}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And I had one Class : ObservableCollection where all directories and files are added to the collection and for every file its icon is converted from file. MyItem class contains few strings for name, extension etc. and one ImageSource for those icons. All worked well till i realised that some folders with different files freezes the program because of converting those icons. So now i bind some general icon for every file and then i want to convert and change it in another thread. So in main class i created global ObservableCollection for items and because i don't know how to load them from the listView back i have moved the filling Collection function from Observable-class to the main class. Now I'm able to change items in listview from new thread but - finally here comes my problem - i get XamlParseException - Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject. When i tried to change file's name (string) it worked perfectly (so far  I'm testing it only on button click)! I tried to implement dependencyObject to MyItem class according to some reference i found on the internet but it didn't worked. This changing icon function.

```
for (int i = leftDirectories.Length; i < (leftDirectories.Length + leftFiles.Length); i++)
        {
            FileToImageIconConverter some = new FileToImageIconConverter(locationLeft + leftFiles[i - leftDirectories.Length].Name);
            ImageSource imgSource = some.Icon;
            leftFilesLoad[i].itemIcon = imgSource;
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
                    {
                        contentLeft.Items.Refresh();
                    }
            );
```

Quite long article, stackoverflow says be specific :-D. Thank so much for everyone trying help me. I'm looking forward to your replies and I'm ready to show you all code you'll need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is occurring because you are creating the `ImageSource` on the none-UI thread. Unless you freeze the object, you cannot do this. You're going to want all the UI related logic to included in your `BeginInvoke` call. Try this instead

```
for (int i = leftDirectories.Length; i < (leftDirectories.Length + leftFiles.Length); i++)
{
           this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
           {
               FileToImageIconConverter some = new FileToImageIconConverter(locationLeft + leftFiles[i - leftDirectories.Length].Name);
               ImageSource imgSource = some.Icon;
               leftFilesLoad[i].itemIcon = imgSource;
               contentLeft.Items.Refresh();
            }
    );
}
```

That should keep all UI related activity on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, you were right, i just had to put leftFilesLoad[i].itemIcon = imgSource; to dispatcher function. Please, is there any way in c# to load items FROM listView in some ObservableCollection variable?

Comment: @Daniel You want to get the items back out of your `Listview`? If you have a reference to the `ListView`, you can get at the collection of bound items through the `ItemsSource` property. Just cast it to the appropriate list type and then you can iterate over it and add those items to your other `ObservableCollection`. Does that answer you question?